# How to assign parent ids to children in xml with multiple levels

Tags: python-3.x, elementtree

Hi I have a situation where i need to parse through xml and find all its corresponding children and set the parent id based on tag they fall under.

Please find the xml

```
<response success="true">
   <output>
      <levels seqNo="5069">
         <level id="1" isLinked="0" hasChildren="true">
            <level id="1051" isLinked="0" hasChildren="true">
               <level id="951" isLinked="0" hasChildren="true">
                  <level id="1073" isLinked="0" hasChildren="true">
                     <level id="922" isElimination="0" isLinked="0" />
                     <level id="957" isLinked="0" />
                     <level id="1301" isLinked="0">
                        <level id="927" isLinked="0" />
                        <level id="939" isLinked="0" />
                     </level>
                     <level id="1302" isLinked="0" hasChildren="true">
                        <level id="925" isLinked="0" />
                     </level>
                  </level>
               </level>
            </level>
         </level>
      </levels>
   </output>
</response>
```

I have tried below code which extracts all the children but not sure how to set parent ids

```
tree = et.parse(r"responseLevels.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
print(root)
for i in root.iter():
    for j in list(i):
        print(j.tag,j.attrib)
```

output I am looking for:

```
id  islinked    haschildren Parent
1   0            "true" 
1051    0          "true"   1
951 0             "true"    1051
1073    0          "true"   951
922 0                       1073
957 0                       1073
1301    0                       1073
927 0                       1301
939 0                       1301
1302    0           "true"  1073
925 0                       1302
```

Comment: Are you able to use [lxml](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html)? Getting the parent (with `getparent()`) is much easier in lxml.

Comment: No I have not used that.. I was using elementtree..

Comment: Thanks Daniel this worked like a charm...

Comment: from lxml import etree
file=(r"file.xml")
with open(file) as fobj:
    xml=fobj.read()
root=etree.fromstring(xml)
for i in root.iter("level"):
    #print(i.attrib,"-->",i.getparent().attrib)
    if i.attrib["id"]=='1':
        i.attrib["parent"]=" "
        print(i.attrib)
    else:
        i.attrib["parent"]=i.getparent().attrib["id"]
        print(i.attrib)

Comment: You should add that as an answer. You can accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it. :-)

Comment: I am not able to post solution..It says your code is not formatted properly though it is working fine here for me..